# How to make ffmpeg-normalize work on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, 20.04, ffmpeg

In the past I had ffmpeg-normalize, now I don't, I don't remember how did I get it.
Now I tried to install it with pip3, but when I type `ffmpeg-normalize...` it says `ffmpeg-normalize: command not found`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have run into a little oddity of pip3's default installation directory and Ubuntu's recognition of this in the `$PATH` statement. Easy enough to rectify though with the following 2 simple steps:

**1. Initial Installation:**

First install `ffmpeg-normalize` as recommended on [it's git home page](https://github.com/slhck/ffmpeg-normalize):

```
sudo apt install python3-pip ffmpeg
pip3 install ffmpeg-normalize
```

Note that the default pip3 installation is actually in `~/.local/bin` as I demonstrate below:

```
andrew@ithaca:~$ find $HOME -name ffmpeg-normalize
/home/andrew/.local/bin/ffmpeg-normalize
andrew@ithaca:~$
```

On installation this will not be *immediately* recognised by Ubuntu as being on the `$PATH`, this is the issue that you have encountered.

**2. Fixing the $PATH Issues:**

Ubuntu is actually already set for this installation path. If you have a look at the file `~/.profile` you will see the following:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

This guarantees that after reboot or when specifically sourced from the command line `ffmpeg-normalize` will be found. On my own system I can demonstrate the syntax to manually source `~/.profile` and kickstart `ffmpeg-normalize`:

```
andrew@ithaca:~$ source ~/.profile
andrew@ithaca:~$ ffmpeg-normalize --version
ffmpeg-normalize v1.20.2
andrew@ithaca:~$
```

Either do this manually as I have demonstrated or simply reboot your computer. This worked well on my system and should on yours as well!